# How to send user identity across servers using mule esb?

Tags: rest, authentication, mule

We are trying to connect multiple RESTful services together using Mule ESB. One of our requirements is that the logged-in user should be available in all back-end servers. How could we satisfy such a requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not the work of an integration engine, it can help for sure, but the main piece of work should be done by a single sign on engine like:

- [JOSSO](http://www.josso.org/confluence/display/JOSSO1/JOSSO+-+Java+Open+Single+Sign-On+Project+Home)
- [CAS](https://www.apereo.org/cas)

Comment: Thank you! Using CAS with Proxy Tickets did the job.